# ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist viewbag stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, dynamic, viewbag, dropdownlistfor

I am unable to get value of id form dynamic dropdownlist using viewbag, I am using a stored procedure to insert the data. The value of id is coming from the dynamic dropdown.

In my view I am using

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", new SelectList(ViewBag.data, "depId", "depId"), "Department-ID")
```

Whereas in my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var Dictionary = db.departments.ToList();

    if (Dictionary != null) 
    {
         ViewBag.data = Dictionary;
    }

    return View();
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult CreateThroughStoreProcedure(employee emp) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ShowdDetails(emp.name, emp.city, emp.gender, emp.depId);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View("Error");
}
```

Comment: You've called the field in your view `DepartmentID`, but in your `employee` model you appear to be looking for a value called `depId`.

Comment: DepartmentID is the dropdownlist name, and emp.DepartmentID is showing error;

Comment: And *what* is the error?

Comment: Its not showing in the IntelliSenseemp.depId is only showing in IntelliSense

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a property on `employee` called `DepartmentID`?  Where do you define the `employee` class?  Please provide all relevant information, this should not be a guessing game on our part.

Comment: employee is my table name
and depId is the data member of employee

Comment: Hurray. ThankYou

Answer (score 2):

You've named your UI field `DepartmentID`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", new SelectList(ViewBag.data, "depId", "depId"), "Department-ID")
```

But the property on your model is `depId`.  Your field names need to match the property names of the model to which you're binding them:

```
@Html.DropDownList("depId", new SelectList(ViewBag.data, "depId", "depId"), "Department-ID")
```